# need a circular dependency between shared (.so) libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, shared-libraries, embedded-linux

I have several shared libraries, loaded in the following order to resolve dependencies: `libA.so` `libMyStuff.so` `libB.so`, where I have the source only for `libMyStuff.so`. Now I need to call a function in `libB.so` from a function in `libMyStuff.so`. (Let us put aside the question whether it is good to leave such dependency in the final version, at the moment I need namely this.)

***How do I have two `.so` libraries call each other?***

I use gcc C/C++, ARM, Android NDK.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Shared libraries can call each other the same way as an executable would call a shared library.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin ***AFAIK*** on Android when you call `loadLibrary()` all functions referenced in the new library must be in already loaded libraries, otherwise you get an _unsatisfied link error_. At least this is what I have seen. Any idea to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic linking, see [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym).